# Modifying MP3 file header text info

Tags: encoding, decoding

Is there a method I can use in a program to access and modify ripped music CD-MP3 file(s) header text?

There is a method available in the MusicMatch jukeboks music player, but with 2000 files ripper from 50 CD's, the job is quite formidable and the tool "supertagging' is cumbersome to use.

What I see for me is more like the visual representation of Excel, where I would have just the three fields Artist name, Song title and Album name. displayed.

The Artist field would have the option of repeating the top field down for all the song titles, Album would always be repeted for all song titles.

Song titles wil of course have to be entered for each item.

In the ripped files, every file has the fields track#, artist, album + some of less importance.

Just let me know if I am at the wrong forum for my search. I just don't know anywhere else that I might go.

For programming I might use Visual Foxpro and/or assembler. I haven't used C since early 1980's.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to develop it yourself, at least use an ID3 library, don't write the functionality yourself!

A good one is at http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/.   I haven't tried it recently, but I'm sure you can call it from VFP somehow.

If you just want something that is better for tagging a shed-load of files, look at MediaMonkey.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work solely in VFP then you should use the VFP low-level utilities
FOPEN()
FCHSIZE( )
FCLOSE( )
FCREATE( )
FEOF( )
FFLUSH( )
FGETS( )
FPUTS( )
FREAD( )
FSEEK( )
FWRITE( )
These are pretty well documented within the VFP Help system and there are numerous examples on the web.

With them you can get the 'raw' data from the MP3 file, identify what you are looking for, change it, and write it back again.

The downside is that specific 'fields' (e.g. Artist name, Song title and Album name, etc.) will not be readily recognized.  You would need to write code to identify these and then identify where the values reside.

Good Luck